# Exporting MS access Report to MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am doing a simple vba script that looks for a file. If it exsits it deletes it. then it moves on to the DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport. Below is the an example of the actual code i am using. The problem i am running into is when i set the auto open to true. I want the file to open after it exports the report. However i am finding that for some reason the program stalls and will sit there for atleast 5 to 10 minutes then it will error out saying that the remote proceedure can not be completed. After the error the file opens anyway with no apparent errors... When i change the auto open to false. I am able to open the report in about 3 to 5 seconds later by manually opening it. Is there something i do not know or can not find that is causing this latancy issue?

Example code - Some things might be syntacticly wrong as i dont have the code infront of me. But it should still communicate what im doing.

```
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim cnn As Access.Application

strFile = "C:Myfile.rtf"
If Len(Dir(strFile)) Then
Kill strFile
End If

'access connection stuff here

with cnn
     'dont display messages code
     'active connection to my database code
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strFile, acFormatRTF, OutputFile, True
      .Quit
End With
```

so again the issue i am having is that i can not seem to get the file to automatically open after access populates it with the report. I am simply trying to increase the preformance or find a work around if you know of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an application which exports from Access 2007, I saved the export operation as an export specification and used :

`CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(NameOfSpecification).Execute False`

I then used

```
Set AppWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application") ' create an instance of Word

Set Doc = AppWord.Documents.Open(NameOfDocument)

AppWord.Visible = True                      ' instance is invisible by default
```

I tend to avoid `DoCmd` if there's a VBA way of doing it: VBA gives me more control.

Comment: Never Mind i just had to move the visable tag to a new spot works like a charm thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I cut this out of a much larger file. Example updated.