# Access report export to a word file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to export an access report to a .docx file?

At the moment we export only .pdf but also need the word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the pdf open with Adobe Acrobat, you can simply save as a Word file.

File > Save as > Microsoft Word > Word Document

The same goes for Microsoft Word if you decide to export it as a RTF file and still want to convert to .doc or .docx.

File > Save as > Word Document

**VBA Route**:
Exporting a report to word format (.doc & docx) are not supported in the Docmd.OutputTo.
However there looks like there is a method that will work the way you want it to found here: [Exporting MS access Report to MS Word using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575092/exporting-ms-access-report-to-ms-word-using-vba)

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be accomplished with the Docmd.OutputTo method.

Here is a link to the formal documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx

Here is a one-line example of how I would do it:

```
Docmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptMyReport", acFormatRTF, "C:\Users\User\Documents\MyExportedReport.rtf"
```

However, while this method can export it as an rtf (which can be opened in Word), it can't do it as a docx. Does this report need to be converted to that docx format? If so, a little more complicated procedure may need to be involved to accomplish this.

Comment: It is needed in .doc or prefered in docx. How near is an rtf output to a word doc?

Comment: DOCs allow you to format your document in any which way you want it to appear while RTF just provides simple options like boldface, italics, font sizes, and types ~ [Reference](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-rtf-and-doc/) What it really comes down to is will the users be editting the report further in Word once it's exported. If so, then the docx route may be the best option. However, to save yourself writing more complicated code, you could have the users convert the rtf to a docx manually once they open it in Word to make modifications to it.